# Is there a way to change the Top Navigation tab titles to be lower case

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

Currently inside my top navigation bar the tab titles will be shown in upper case such as ; PAGE,ITEMS,DOCUMENTS, etc. so is there a way to chnage these titles to only start with upper case, so they become, "Page" instead of "PAGE", "Events" instead of "EVENTS", etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there should be two approaches:

1. There should be a style somewhere in your CSS files that makes your tab names uppercase. You can search for "text-transform: uppercase" and just delete this style.
2. You can override this style with a new one. In your browser, press F12 and find the CSS-classes related to the tabs. Find your main CSS-file in your styles library or wherever your hold your styles. Insert this in it:

.MyTabClass {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.MyTabClass:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

**Update:**

In case of seatle.master you can apply these styles:

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text
{
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text:first-letter
{
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

If it does not work - then try the same thing with !important keyword:

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text
{
 text-transform: lowercase !important;
}

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text:first-letter
{
 text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

**Update 2:**

I think, it's much easier to check if there is an additional style applied for uppercasing not looking through CSS-files or master-page, but using browser developer tools like on the screenshot below. Just select your HTML tag that turns out to be in upper case and check if there are some custom styles applied. Then you can easily see the source file that contains this custom style.

[image: Uppercase style]

Comment: i search the seatle.master page , but it does not contain any thing related to text-transform ? can the text transformation being done using javaScript ? as when i use the firebug tool on this page, it will show these tabs title in lower case under the HTML section?

Comment: Oh, you are using standard seatle.master? Then try applying these styles: 


.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text
{
text-transform: lowercase;

}


.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text:first-letter
{
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

If it does not work - then try the same thing with !important keyword:

.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text
{
text-transform: lowercase !important;

}


.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li .menu-item-text:first-letter
{
 text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

To do so search for these tabs inside the following folder:-
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources
search for these tab titles inside the core & core.en-Us files,
you will able to modify the title for the items,files,browse,document,events, calendar
by doing something like below

```
<data name="cui_CalendarTabTitle">
    <value>Custom title...</value>
  </data>
```

Comment: yes i can chnage them from there , but even if i set them as lowercase, they are being displayed as upper case. for example i have the folloiwng <data name="cui_EventsTabTitle">
    <value>Events Options</value>
  </data> . but it is being displayed as EVENTS OPTIONS on the layout.